# Subtracting row values in Cognos

Tags: cognos

I have the following report:

```
Id   Product    Revenue   Month
1     A          302        jan
1     A          342        feb
1     A          133        mar
```

For this report, I need to find the difference in revenues for months, i.e difference in revenue from Jan to Feb and feb to march. 
I want to add another column like this:

```
  Id   Product    Revenue   Month  Profit
    1     A          302     jan
    1     A          342     feb     40
    1     A          142     mar    -200
```

I can write a case statement for it and create a Calculated field but I don't know how to refer the rows to do my subtraction. Can someone help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens when you try running-difference([Revenue])?